# MS Access - Time Series Aggregation / Analysis Query

Tags: datetime, ms-access-2010, aggregate-functions

MS ACCESS2010 - Trying to Count the number of trades made before certain intervals during the day (1pm, 2pm, 3pm, etc.) I have a table of all trades with their times but cannot figure out how to aggregate the data by the desired intervals on one sheet. I can create a query for each interval but there has to be something more efficient?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the hour:

```
Select Hour([DateTimeField]), Sum([TradeField])
From YourTable
Group By Hour([DateTimeField])
```

Comment: Thank you Gustav - Very Helpful